# Changing the select parameters by calling ->select twice?

Tags: database, yii

I had a query:

```
$query = 
  Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
    ->select('*')
    ->from('products p')
    ->limit(5);
```

And then I got results:

```
$result = $query->queryAll();
```

How can I use the existing query object, without rewriting it, to re-instantiate the values for "select" and "limit". I want to change select to "count(p.productid)" and unset limit. I tried the following but it does not work:

```
$query = 
  Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
    ->select('*')
    ->from('products p')
    ->limit(5);

$result = $query->queryAll();


$query = 
  $query
    ->select('count(p.productid)')
    ->limit(-1);
$result2 = $query->queryRow();
```

This still returns the result of the first select?

**EDIT**

Basically, I want to RESET the select. It looks like it builds on the select. So, I think you can do this:

```
$query = 
 $query->select('something')
    ->select('somethingElse')
    ->select('somethingMoreStuff');
```

My problem is that I want to "reset" the select. So basically UNDO these selects. Is this possible?

Comment: You can simply use count function ClassName::model->count();

Comment: Doesn't work in the context that I'm doing it. Please explain in detail?

Comment: @NanheKumar Except `ClassName::model->count()` is for Active Record requests. So the first question is do you absolutely need to use DAO and the query builder or can you use the Active Record abstraction?

Comment: post you complete code where you are using this code in model and how you are calling this function from controller i think your model class name will be Product then you can count echo Product::model->count(); or $query =Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)->select(array('count(*) as num'))->from('products');

Comment: my problem is: "how do I overwrite the select function" ... not: "how do I get the count?"

Comment: The problem is that when you call `queryAll()` a lot of internal properties are changed so I don't think you can reuse the same `$query` object to perform a different query.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do:

```
$intialQuery = 
  Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
    ->from('products p');

$query = $intialQuery 
    ->select('*')
    ->limit(5);

$query2 = $intialQuery
    ->select('count(p.productid) as number')
    ->limit(-1);

$result = $query->queryAll();
$result2 = $query2->queryRow();
```

Comment: Because it's still double code. All I want to do is RESET the select. See my last edit.

Comment: There is no double code in what I put since I add only the changing values to the second and the third queries! But it's true I use more var than you do.

Comment: I simplified my original problem. I actually have several joins, wheres and more that I don't want to rewrite. All I want is a way to "reset" the current select conditions.

Comment: As i said in a comment on your question I doàn't think you can reuse the same query object after you performed a `queryAll` request. May be you could try to copy the object before performing the first query. And in the code that i put above, u can put you joins in `$originalQuery`